# Is it possible to install VMware on a Virtual Private Server?

Tags: virtualization, windows-server-2008-r2, vps

I recently purchase a VPS hosting package,
which allows me to have full root access to Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2. 
I can access the VPS with Remote Desktop and install any application I like.

I tried to install VMware Workstation and or VMware Player.

The installation failed with with little explaintion as to why.

I understand what I am trying to do is put virtual environment on top of already virtualised environment, so was always unlikely to work.

But before I give up any ideas/altenatives.

Comment: It really depends on where you hosted it and what their policy is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is technically possible if you install the VMware ESX hypervisor as the first thing on your VPS. You can then run one virtual machine with MS windows 2008, and then anything else in other virtual machines.

The problem you will find is that most cloud/VPS hosting companies have a limited number of templates for you to install from. Your best bet is to use a VMware based hosting company, where you will be able to upload your own virtual machine or installation media. That way, you can install ESX first, and then any number of other virtual machines according to the resources you have available.

The VMware blog has a recent post on getting started with VMware hosting. http://blogs.vmware.com/vcloud/2011/05/cloud-hosting-with-vmware.html

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the eventlogs for errors?

Hosting multiple machines on one host would depend on your system spec. My initial thoughts we be that virtual inside of virtual is not recommended (unless I have read your question wrong, appears to be what you are asking).